# Capitalization issue with Workbooks.Open using VBA in Excel 2016

Tags: macos, vba, excel

I am trying to write code that will prompt the user for a .xlsx file path and then open that workbook. Eventually, I will want VBA to copy data from the workbook it is opening. But, I am not able to get VBA to open a workbook.

Here is my code:

```
    Sub Select_File_Or_Files_Mac()
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyScript As String
Dim MyFiles As String
Dim MySplit As Variant
Dim N As Long
Dim Fname As String
Dim mybook As Workbook

On Error Resume Next
MyPath = MacScript("return (path to documents folder) as String")
'Or use MyPath = "Macintosh HD:Users:Ron:Desktop:TestFolder:"

' In the following statement, change true to false in the line "multiple
' selections allowed true" if you do not want to be able to select more
' than one file. Additionally, if you want to filter for multiple files, change
' {""com.microsoft.Excel.xls""} to
' {""com.microsoft.excel.xls"",""public.comma-separated-values-text""}
' if you want to filter on xls and csv files, for example.
MyScript = _
"set applescript's text item delimiters to "","" " & vbNewLine & _
           "set theFiles to (choose file of type " & _
         " {""org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet""} " & _
           "with prompt ""Please select a file or files"" default location alias """ & _
           MyPath & """ multiple selections allowed true) as string" & vbNewLine & _
           "set applescript's text item delimiters to """" " & vbNewLine & _
           "return theFiles"

MyFiles = MacScript(MyScript)
On Error GoTo 0

If MyFiles <> "" Then
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    MySplit = Split(MyFiles, ",")
    For N = LBound(MySplit) To UBound(MySplit)

        ' Get the file name only and test to see if it is open.
        Fname = Right(MySplit(N), Len(MySplit(N)) - InStrRev(MySplit(N), Application.PathSeparator, , 1))
        If bIsBookOpen(Fname) = False Then

            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MySplit(N))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "You open this file : " & MySplit(N) & vbNewLine & _
                       "And after you press OK it will be closed" & vbNewLine & _
                       "without saving, replace this line with your own code."
                mybook.Close SaveChanges:=False
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "We skipped this file : " & MySplit(N) & " because it Is already open."
        End If
    Next N
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End If

    Cells(1, 1) = MyFiles

    Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyFiles)

    End Sub

    Function bIsBookOpen(ByRef szBookName As String) As Boolean
    ' Contributed by Rob Bovey
On Error Resume Next
bIsBookOpen = Not (Application.Workbooks(szBookName) Is Nothing)
    End Function
```

When I run the code, I get a 1004 run-time error saying the file could not be found with the file path in all caps. This is odd as the user has to select the file in a pop up window so the file HAS to be there. I also have the code write the file path to cell 1,1 in the spreadsheet. Whats weird is the file path the program prints has the proper casing as the actual file path, but the error is in all caps. I think the issue is that unix is case sensitive and I am running this on OSX. why is Excel putting the file path in all caps? This also happens if I hard code the file path to Workbooks.Open(direct file path here)

I am using code I found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh710200(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be missing

```
' Change drive/directory to MyPath.
ChDrive MyPath
ChDir MyPath
```

Comment: Tsolina, I put in those two lines of code and I am now receiving a run-time error '76'